# Differences Between Search Appliance vs Search Software

Tags: asp.net, search-engine

Can anyone explain the differences/advantages between a Search appliance (physical piece of hardware put on the server) vs Search software installed on the server?  New to setting up a search for an intranet.  There's many choices but not sure what the advantages & disadvantages are.

JS

Comment: There are no advantages and disadvantages, there are differences. You can write down these differences yourself just fine by comparing various products. Whether each property/difference is beneficial for you, only you can answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, now a days it's better to use search engines as software (ie. lucene / solr / elasticsearch). It will give you alternatives to compose index the way you want and also, scale horizontally if you need.

Using an appliance, you'll have the search engine built in the server and you'll be a able scale vertically or you need to buy a cluster from the provider. I don't see advantages using this second one.